# xslt 1.0 select first n elements whose child element is one of allowed values

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have one xml, and I have to find first n element whose child element has one of allowed value
e.g. for following xml, I want to select element whose state is WA or NY. List of allowed state is dynamic value so I can't use

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="element[(state='WA' or state='NY')]"/>
```

when I am trying to filter it with contains, nothing is happening. e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="allowedListPadded">;WA;NY;</xsl:variable>
<xslt:apply-templates select="element[contains($allowedListPadded,concat(';',state,';'))]"/>
```

XML:

```
<items>
  <element>
    <state>WA</state>
    <title>Washington</title>
  </element>
  <element>
    <state>OR</state>
    <title>Oragon</title>
  </element>
  <element>
    <state>NY</state>
    <title>New York</title>
  </element>
  <element>
    <state>WA</state>
    <title>Washington News</title>
  </element>
  <element>
    <state>TX</state>
    <title>Texas</title>
  </element>
</items>
```

I was thinking to filter elements in apply-templates and then in template, wants to use position() < n. However got stuck  with first part only.

complete xslt as asked.

```
<xslt:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
  exclude-result-prefixes="xslt">
  <xslt:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" />
<xslt:template match="root">
    <xslt:text>{"statelist":</xslt:text>
    <xslt:choose>
      <xslt:when test="$allowedListPadded=''">        
        <!-- if no list is present, give default state -->
        <xslt:apply-templates select="element[state = 'WA']"/>
      </xslt:when>
      <xslt:otherwise>
        <xslt:apply-templates select="element[contains(allowedListPadded,concat(';',state,';'))]"/>
      </xslt:otherwise>
    </xslt:choose>
    <xslt:text>}</xslt:text>
  </xslt:template>
</xslt:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your variable approach should have worked if it didn't have a typo - you're missing a closing parenthesis `<xsl:apply-templates select="element[contains($allowedListPadded,state)]"/>`

Comment: I wrote it here while writing question. Else it has proper ending parenthesis

Comment: You'll need to share more of your stylesheet then, the problem may be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xslt:apply-templates select="element[contains(allowedListPadded,concat(';',state,';'))][position() &lt; 5]"/>
```

The trick here is not using an *and* operator in your predicate, but to use two predicates. The first one creates a node-set including the selected elements, and the second one returns a node-set with 5 (for example) elements of this node-set.

Comment: your are write about using second predicate. However currently I am not getting even single output, so there is no point putting second filter for position(). at least my current code should have given me WA and NY

Answer (score 0):

You are matching `root` element and there isn't any `root` element in your xml. You must change that and match `items` element. Your approach:

```
<xslt:variable name="allowedListPadded">;WA;NY;</xslt:variable>
<xslt:apply-templates select="element[contains($allowedListPadded,concat(';',state,';'))]"/>
```

should work then.